# How to unlock a table in IBM DB2 Data Studio 3.1?

Tags: db2, locking

I know the process to unlock a table through IBM DB2 Control Center using activity monitor, but I am completely new to IBM DB2 Data Studio 3.1 Administrative Tool. **Whenever i am right clicking on that particular table only, and clicking on edit data***(to update the records in the table)*, i get the error `com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-668, SQLSTATE=-57016,SQLERMC=-7`;
How do i unlock it using IBM DB2 Datastudio 3.1?

Comment: Can you explain the process of what you are trying to do? Are you asking how to create an event monitor through Data Studio 3.1?

Comment: Chris: I have updated the question with the errors that i got during execution.

Comment: Interestingly enough, when I look up that error it appears that it is because of a DDL statement that places the table in a state that requires a REORG. Try that first.

Comment: Is there any reference for how to use the REORG Command in IBM DB2 Data Studio 3.1?

Comment: You can either type it in the Command Editor. Or you can right-click on the table and select Manage | Reorg Table.... Then follow the editor to run it.

Comment: Did that work? Did it resolve your issue?

Answer (score 2):

Three unlock table commands are

```
    COMMIT
    ROLLBACK
    DISCONNECT
```

Comment: WarrenT : Can you please guide how to use this commands for what i am trying is ROLLBACK TABLE_NAME which gives an error.

Comment: ROLLBACK http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r1/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000992.html

Answer (score 1):

There is no `UNLOCK TABLE` statement in DB2. Locks are released
automatically upon commit or rollback.

Comment: Have you noticed that you linked to the Informix manual? There is no `UNLOCK TABLE` statement in DB2. Locks are released automatically upon commit or rollback.

Comment: How embarrassing. (looking down)